# Hybrid-Analysis.com indicates macOS built-in file is contacting a malicious website

Tags: mojave, firewall, malware, anti-virus

I'm wondering if anyone knows why this

`/System/Library/StagedFrameworks/Safari/WebKit.framework/Versions/A/XPCServices/com.apple.WebKit.Networking.xpc`

is connecting to `adriver.ru` ?

This is according to Little Snitch on my macOS 10.14.6 Mojave machine, that I just updated from 10.11.6 OS X Lion.

Hybrid-Analysis makes it appear "at first glance" that it is a potentially malicious website : https://www.hybrid-analysis.com/sample/aeb562d94494fd967c0ef064f528956192bcff8b00033c0f9892d7cafeda174e?environmentId=120

However, I'm not familiar with Hybrid-Analysis very well...

Is this Little Snitch paranoia?

Comment: I would appreciate to know **why** my post was voted down anonymously...perhaps I could improve it...?

Comment: I'd just block it and not worry about it! -- I too use **Little Snitch** but I also keep my `/etc/hosts` _file_ updated with this https://someonewhocares.org/hosts/ _file_ and "adriver.ru" is one that get blocked in that _file_.

Comment: @user3439894 What is someonewhocares.org ? Is this a standard resource, or just a grassroots attempt to help protect people with internet connections?

Comment: So did you research someonewhocares.org? What did you find? What does google show?

Comment: This is like saying a Ford car is driving to an illegal gathering and asking why Ford does that. What are you trying to do here? You asked a yes no question so the down votes might be because it’s not clear what practical problem you face.

Answer (score 2):

WebKit is a standard component - it will connect to anywhere it's told to. That's why we have ad-blockers & Little Snitch; to shut down random calls to unsavoury locations.

Little Snitch is 'smart' but its job is to tell you when a connection asks, not to identify or police for you what is at the other end of that connection. That's your call. If you don't like the look of a connection, look it up or just deny it. if it later turns out you made the wrong call, you can reverse it in Little Snitch's rules.

Ad blockers will attempt to police these connections for you, but are usually browser only, not global.

Each has its advantages & disadvantages - one being that every so often you have to research what/where/why something connects… or fails to.